# How to run JQuery after the main php page include sub php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am building my website and in the main PHP page, I got something like this:

```
...
<a class="aboutMe" href="?section=aboutMe"></a>
<a class="network" href="?section=network"></a>
<a class="map" href="?section=map"></a>
...
```

If someone click any of the links above, the in the same page, the PHP will do this:

```
<?php
if(array_key_exists ("section", $_REQUEST)) {
  if($_REQUEST["section"] == "aboutMe") {
    include(app_path().'/views/about-me.blade.php');
  } 
  else if($_REQUEST["section"] == "network") {
    include(app_path().'/views/network/index.php');
  } 
  else if($_REQUEST["section"] == "map") {
    include(app_path().'/views/my-trace.php');
  }  
}
?>
```

After the sub page is road, it is placed right under the main page, and I would like to make it automatically scroll down to the joint part so the user could see the sub page immediately, something like this:

```
<main page>
       <- scroll to here
<sub page>
```

It sounds not difficult, and I've already written some jQuery to do this job. However the whole page was refreshed after the including, and the jQuery is run before the fresh. How could I fix that?

Or is that possible to include sub pages without refresh the whole page? This would be a preferred solution. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you do not want the page to refresh you should use jQuery to accomplish this. Look at using [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Wow! Quick, simple and beautiful! Problem solved! Thanks so much Ssergei!

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server. It sends a response to the user's browser, then javascript runs in the browser. If you want to execute more PHP code after the response has been sent, the user has to send another request to the server and get a new response. You can do this without reloading the page using ajax: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Alternatively, if there are only the three different pages, you could just include the html code for all three pages in the initial response. Then just use javascript to change what is visible.